# CSS não carrega, Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html

Tags: css

Olá galera estou trabalhando em um projeto MVC porem me deparei com um erro em css que nunca tinha acontecido comigo. Ao estanciar o CSS o navegador me retorna um erro de renderização.

no firefox:

> 12:08:16.973 A folha de estilos http://localhost/portfolio/generic.css foi carregada como CSS, embora seu tipo MIME, “text/html”, não seja “text/css”.1 portfolio

No google chrome:

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html:

Alguém sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Está usando windows e apache?

Comment: Talvez na hora da importação você não tenha inferido que é um "stylesheet".

Comment: estou usando ubuntu e apache, ja testei permissões e nada, li um artigo onde o cara coloca no htaccess o seguinte codigo : RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d  testei aqui e deu certo, porem não sei se é o mais viável fazer isso.

Comment: Este código não tem nada haver com isto, este código é para urls reescritas, diga-me você está usando `.htaccess`, tem como postar ele na pergunta?

Comment: Isso me parece erro na configuração do apache! Você tem acesso ao arquivo /etc/apache2/mime.types? Sabe se existe alguma entrada para css nele?

Comment: Provavelmente é configuração do apache, você disse que é MVC, geralmente em MVC há uma pasta para o conteúdo público estático que é configurada no apache para não mostrar as pastas privadas de código, o seu css fica num local direto como `/var/www/portfolio/generic.css` ou em outra subpasta como `/var/www/portfolio/public/generic.css` ?

Comment: Tens razão @JairoCorrea agora que notei isto. Brendol por favor informe qual framework MVC está usando.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers fazem request HTTP para servidores. O servidor, então, retorna uma response HTTP.

Ambos, request e response consistem em um monte de cabeçalhos e um corpo (por vezes opcional) com algum conteúdo nele.

Se há um corpo, em seguida, um dos cabeçalhos é o Content-Type, que descreve o que o corpo é (é um documento HTML? Uma imagem? O conteúdo de um envio de formulário? Etc).

Quando você pede pelo seu Stylesheet, o seu servidor está dizendo ao navegador que se trata de um documento HTML (Content-Type: text/html) em vez de uma folha de estilo (Content-Type: text/css).

Use a guia de Network do navegador para examinar a request que está indo para o servidor e sua response. Através do que aparecer lá você será capaz de descobrir onde está colocando o Content-Type para text/html